# intel atom getting too hot

Tags: 12.04, kernel, shutdown, overheating

I own an Asus 1215N which is getting very hot

Intel Atom 525D dual core
ION 2 (geforce 220 + GMA 3150)
4 GB RAM
Ubuntu 12.04

it hits 86 C at idle. Some times (at load or turned on > 1 hour) it shuts down due to heat, in Windows 7 it runs idle at 49 C. I tried an acpi call to shut down the nVidia chip which is cooled together with the Atom chip. That didn't solve the problem. To check up to see if it really turned off I checked how much power the laptop consumed, it only went from using 1400 mW to 860 mW, no changes in heat.
I also tried reapply the standard heat adhesive, the old heat adhesive made it run at 97 (it couldn't even put up a useful install of Ubuntu). This really annoys me, as Ubuntu is the OS of choice to me.

Should I try compile the kernel?

Is it true that compile for a P4 is the better choice to the atom, when compiling the kernel for this processor architecture?

Now I tried compiling the kernel for atom. Now temperature is 83 C (think the drop has more to do with ambient temp than the customized kernel)

help appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to clean the laptop? My 1201n gets up to 80 in the gpu when it's dirty, when it's clean it's an easy 56 degrees. the cpu is also 20 degrees cooler when cleaned...

Answer (score 0):

Look I had a temperature problem but not that much. My laptop was about 65 C (high performance), and the fan was working too fast. I found out that my graphics card drivers (AMD Catalyst - not the same as you) were not installed and I couldn't, so I installed them manually from terminal and then the temperature is now about 53 C and the fan works perfectly. To see if you have installed them go to System Settings > Additional Drivers

Comment: jupiter setting is on demand, it does it even on powersaver (225 Mhz). I have tried it with the nVidia proprietary driver, even with bumblebee. It's the same.

Comment: jupiter doesn't really affect the processors preformance, it controls stuff like brightness etc to make your battery last longer. Anyway, I might be wrong, my knowledge is restricted on this kind of stuff, but an advice is don't use Ubuntu until you find a solution, 86 C at idle is way too much and probably gonna damage your hardware.

Comment: jupiter (with the eee pc extras) setting is on demand, it does it even on powersaver (225 Mhz). I have tried the nVidia proprietary driver, even with bumblebee. It's the same. On the other hand I do not want to shut my nVidia card off, at least when I'm home. As I have a large secondary monitor. That the intel GMA does not support.

Comment: I only use it from USB, trying fedora and Arch now.

Comment: I think it is probably a kernel thing, so another distribution will probably not fix it. But I think you got better chances with fedora achieving it.

Comment: you were right, it didn't fix a thing, I'm back at square one. Just hoped it, as I read Ubuntu 12.04 still has some of 11.10's issues in power efficiency. Think I'm gonna try compile kernel and do some research on power saving